# How to convert string to date in react native with moment.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, date, momentjs, utc

I have this date in string, now i want to convert this with UTC using moment.js.

`Wednesday, 22 September 2021, 7:00:00 am`

Expected result:

Formate: `DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a`

Date: `22-Sep-2021 12:30 PM`

I tried this way but not working

```js
let dateStr = 'Wednesday, 22 September 2021, 7:00:00 am'
utcDate = moment(moment(dateStr, 'DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a'))
  .utc()
  .format('DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm A');
```

Also I tried this conversion with `dayjs` but it works well in iOS but not in Android where I get `null`.

```
utcDate = dayjs(new Date(`${dateStr} UTC`)).format(
  'DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm A',
);
```

let me know if anyone have solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: What result do you get after `format()`? By the way, you don't need double construction of `moment`, `(moment(dateStr, 'DD-MMM-YYYY hh:mm a').utc()` is enough (this may also solve your problem).

Comment: i tried it will single also it's also not working, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let dateStr = 'Wednesday, 22 September 2021, 7:00:00 am'
const utcDate = moment(new Date(dateStr))
  .utc()
  .format('DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm A');

console.log(utcDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: i tried this, but getting "Invalid date" in android and "22 Sep 2021, 01:30 AM" in iOS.
But actual date will be "22 Sep 2021, 12:30 PM"

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the format from `moment` call.

**You can do this but it is a deprecated way**

```js
let dateStr = 'Wednesday, 22 September 2021, 7:00:00 am'
// You can do this but it is deprecated way
const date = moment(dateStr)
  .utc()
  .format('DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm A');

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**The better solution.**

```js
let dateStr = 'Wednesday, 22 September 2021, 7:00:00 am'
const date = moment(new Date(dateStr))
  .utc()
  .format('DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm A');

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried this, but getting "Invalid date" in android and "22 Sep 2021, 01:30 AM" in iOS.
But actual date will be "22 Sep 2021, 12:30 PM"